# Localization in Ajax Datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I am trying to figure out a way to display Datatable language based on the local language of the Server/PC.
The idea is that based on the language it should load the respective language file.The question may sound trivial, but i dont have much JavaScript experience.
After some hours of Internet research thought i could use something like that:

```
  if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#systemStatusTable' ) ) {
                datatable = $('#systemStatusTable').DataTable({
                 var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
                    if (userLang.startsWith("de")) {
                        language: {
                               url: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug- 
                                                                  
                               ins/1.10.20/i18n/German.json'                                                      
       }
                          }
                       }

                });
```

but it give me error on the line with userLang - Unexpected Identifier UserLang

Also generally i am not quite sure if this will work this way or if its the best option to achieve that goal.Any tips ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Move your JavaScript logic to before you declare your DataTable. Currently that logic is _inside_ the DataTable - and that is not part of what DataTables understands. You cannot just place any arbitrary JavaScript in a DataTables initialization block. Once you have determined what your `userSpecificUrl` variable needs to be, you _can_ use that variable inside your DataTables logic: `url: userSpecificUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement can not be inside datatables initialization.

This is how to make it :

```
   var lang = 'English';
   var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
   if (userLang.startsWith("de")) {
     lang = 'German';
   }
   var datatable = $('#systemStatusTable').DataTable({
       "language": {
            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/"+lang+".json"
        }
    });
```